# Prove that if $f$ is monotone, then the four Dini derivatives of $F$ are measureable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The Dini derivatives of $F$ at $x$:

(i). The *upper right derivative* $\overline{D^+}F(x):=\limsup\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\inf\limits_{\delta}\sup\limits_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$

(ii). The *low right derivative* $\underline{D^+}F(x):=\liminf\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\sup\limits_{\delta}\inf\limits_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$

(iii). The *upper left derivativ*e $\overline{D^-}F(x):=\limsup\limits_{h\to 0^-}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\inf\limits_{\delta}\sup\limits_{-\delta<h<0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$

(iv). The *low left derivative* $\underline{D^-}F(x):=\liminf\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\sup\limits_{\delta}\inf\limits_{-\delta<h<0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$

The difficulty is that $h$ rangs over a unconuntable set, the measure theory does not work in uncountable case.

Comment: At least the $\delta$ can be replaced with $\frac1n$, without even needing to use monotonicity, but this still leaves the problem of showing why monotonicity implies that things like $\sup\limits_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$ are measurable for each fixed $\delta$.